# DB2 - Where Subquery

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have a problem in db2 with the following tables:

```
Table_1
A       B        C
1       2        1
2       1        2
3       2        2
4       1        1

Table_2
A
1
```

I want to select all `table_1` records with a `B` or `C` greater than the greatest `A` from `table_2`. The result should be:

```
Query
A       B        C
1       2        1
2       1        2
3       2        2
```

which I currently achieve with this query:

```
select A, B, C
from Table_1
where B > (select max(A) from Table_2) 
or    C > (select max(A) from Table_2)
```

Is it possible to only issue one subselect in the where clause to improve performance?

Comment: It may be posible to write `(select max(A) from Table_2) < any (B,C)`. I don't use DB2, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as:

```
select A, B, C
from Table_1
where MAX(B,C) > (select max(A) from Table_2)
```

Note: untested as I have no DB2 database handy.

Here it is in an SQLfiddle in MySQL syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f89c5/3

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you need, then move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
select t1.A, t1.B, t1.C
from Table_1 t1 cross join
     (select max(A) as maxA from table_2) t2
where t1.B > t2.maxA or t1.C > t2.maxA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think vice versa: You want all table1 records for which **not exists** a table2 record with to great an A value:

```
select *
from table_1
where not exists
(
  select *
  from table_2
  where table_2.a >= table_1.b
    and table_2.a >= table_1.c
);
```

By the way: Having just one subquery is great for maintainabilty. A Change to it would have to be made in one place only. But as to speed: In your query the subquery is not correlated to the main query, so it will probably be run just once and its result applied to all checks. (It would be stupid, did the DBMS run the same subquery again and again for each record and column in table_1.)